# Change input background color to white when value is deleted

Tags: javascript, css, textbox, background-color

I have a input control(textbox) whose color is changed if the value is more than 2000. What I am trying to do is when delete the value in textbox the background changes to white.

I have tried :

`document.getElementById("advance").style.background = '#FFFFFF';`

but the textbox still have background color red.

```
if (document.getElementById("no_days").value <= 5) {
            var amt = document.getElementById("advance").value;
            if (amt > 2000) {
                alert("Eligible advance amount is upto 2000Rs");
                ready_to_send = false;
                    document.getElementById("advance").style.background = '#FF0000';
                return;
            }
        }
```

Expected result is when value is more than 2000 background color is red and when I delete the value background color changes to White. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you don't currently have any events, so you're not going to be able to react to input.

Comment: @Utkanos I think, OP is showing the problematic part by skipping the event registration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the background of the textbook turns to white when it is empty, you can attach an event listener for a change in the textbox and find out if the value of the textbox is empty.

```
let textbox = document.getElementById("myInput");

textbox.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
                console.log(this.value);
                //perform your inner logic here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer: 
listen to both events the tap on the button and the Inputchange.

The solution is a simple `else`

```
button.addEventlistener('click', () => {
  if (document.getElementById("no_days").value <= 5) {
     var amt = document.getElementById("advance").value;
     if (amt > 2000) {
        alert("Eligible advance amount is upto 2000Rs");
        ready_to_send = false;
        document.getElementById("advance").style.background = '#FF0000';
   }})

input.addEventlistener('input', () => {
   if (document.getElementById("no_days").value <= 5) {
      var amt = document.getElementById("advance").value;
      if (amt <= 2000) {
         ready_to_send = true;
         document.getElementById("advance").style.background = '#FFF';
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I already tired this as mentioned in my question. this doesn't work when I delete the value. It work's if I refresh the page.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. What do you mean with deleting the value? Can you maybe post more of your code for example the html part because in my test this code worked fine.

Comment: Actually this i check I am using in my webform. For travel less than 5 days the advance allowed is 2000 maximum. if the user enter value more than 2000 than on button click textbox background is turned to red color. But when I edit or delete the value the textbox background color remains red, which I am trying to change to white.

Comment: So you are listening for a click on a button do change the color to red but if the value is changed by the user you want the textfield to get white even if the user don't click the button?

Comment: yes correct, I am trying to change background to white even if the user doesn't click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the oninput event listener to your input box and assign a function to it which will fire every time the input changes:

`<input type="text" id="advance" oninput="myFunction()">`

and add your function that gets called by the oninput event:

```
myFunction(){

var value = document.getElementById("advance").value; 

if(value.length == 0)
{
document.getElementById("advance").style.background = 'white';
}

if(value < 0)
{
//value not valid
//do something
}

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But oniput event i am running another code for not allowing negative values. i.e oninput="validity.valid || (value = '');"

Comment: why not move the valid check to the same function and do both check in the function? I updated my answer to cater for the added logic

Answer (score 0):

Did you use only javascript?

I mean, if you use other frameworks such as Vue.js, there is a problem there.
Because they always try to set their style in real time.
This means, if I drag the button, then they set new style so that we can see it is moving.

In this case, i think you should set it as 'white!important' which sets the background style more important.

My answer is
document.getElementById("advance").style.background = 'white!important';